# msbuild error while compiling (default target) (1) ->

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, mono

When I Build the solution using visual studio it works! but whenever I tried to build it msbuild it throws an error :

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.6.1586.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 03-12-2016 00:10:23.
Project "C:\Users\RAZERAK\Desktop\BBM\BBM.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
The target "_ConvertPdbFiles" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\4.0\Microsoft.Comm
on.targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets (34,37)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "_CollectPdbFiles" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\4.0\Microsoft.Comm
on.targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets (34,70)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "_CollectMdbFiles" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\4.0\Microsoft.Comm
on.targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets (41,38)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "_CopyMdbFiles" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\4.0\Microsoft.Common.
targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets (41,71)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
Project "C:\Users\RAZERAK\Desktop\BBM\BBM.sln" (1) is building "C:\Users\RAZERAK\Desktop\BBM\BBM\BBM.csproj" (2) on nod
e 1 (default targets).
Project file contains ToolsVersion="15.0". This toolset may be unknown or missing, in which case you may be able to res
olve this by installing the appropriate version of MSBuild, or the build may have been forced to a particular ToolsVers
ion for policy reasons. Treating the project as if it had ToolsVersion="4.0". For more information, please see http://g
o.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=291333.
CoreResGen:
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\resgen.exe" /useSourcePath /r:"C:\Program Fi
  les (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86
  )\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll" /r:C:\Users\RAZERAK\Desktop\BBM\packages\
  Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framewo
  rk\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramew
  ork\v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETF
  ramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0
  \System.Deployment.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System
  .dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Drawing.dll" /r:"
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /r:"C:\P
  rogram Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (
  x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /compile Properties\Resources.r
  esx,obj\Debug\Main.Properties.Resources.resources
  Processing resource file "Properties\Resources.resx" into "obj\Debug\Main.Properties.Resources.resources".
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the i
nput files.
CoreCompile:
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:AnyCPU /errorr
  eport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva- /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Micr
  osoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Micr
  osoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll" /reference:C:\Users\RAZERAK\Desktop\BBM\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0
  .1\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFram
  ework\v4.0\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework
  \v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\
  .NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETF
  ramework\v4.0\System.Deployment.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NET
  Framework\v4.0\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\
  v4.0\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4
  .0\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramewor
  k\v4.0\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0
  \System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\BBM.exe /resource:obj\Debug\Main.P
  roperties.Resources.resources /target:winexe /utf8output Config.cs FormBackground.cs FormBackground.Designer.cs FormE
  ncryptedFiles.cs FormEncryptedFiles.Designer.cs FormGame.cs FormGame.Designer.cs Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.c
  s Tools\Blockr.cs Tools\Hacking.cs Tools\Locker.cs Tools\Windows.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Setti
  ngs.Designer.cs "C:\Users\RAZERAK\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
Tools\Blockr.cs(9,45): error CS1002: ; expected [C:\Users\RAZERAK\Desktop\BBM\BBM\BBM.csproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\RAZERAK\Desktop\BBM\BBM\BBM.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Done Building Project "C:\Users\RAZERAK\Desktop\BBM\BBM.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\RAZERAK\Desktop\BBM\BBM.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\RAZERAK\Desktop\BBM\BBM\BBM.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
(CoreCompile target) ->
  Tools\Blockr.cs(9,45): error CS1002: ; expected [C:\Users\RAZERAK\Desktop\BBM\BBM\BBM.csproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.24
```

I am making a Program which will compile solution file using msbuild but it is giving an error when I tried using C:\Windows....\msbuild to compile.
I also tried mono xbuild and it also works!
Please suggest What to do ?

Comment: Look at line 9 of `Tools\Blockr.cs`

Comment: This is 9th line :
private static string BlockrAddress => "http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/"

Comment: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe` - that's not going to work with C# 6... Sounds like you should be using a newer version of msbuild.

Comment: I get this when I follow the link ***A virus or other malicious code has been detected and access has been prohibited.***

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you suggest What to do ?

Comment: ***Can you suggest What to do*** Upgrade your version of Visual Studio.

Comment: @drescherjm A virus ? Which link ?

Comment: As I said, "Sounds like you should be using a newer version of msbuild."

Comment: The link to the source code you posted in a comment. However it could just be a false positive from my internet provider.

Comment: I already stated that it is working with my visual studio 2015 but not with msbuild

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 should have installed a newer version of msbuild.

Comment: Problem Solved I just replace "=>" with "=" in line 9 in Tools\Blockr.cs and it is working fine now

Comment: Can you tell what is causing the error and why visual studio is able to compile it successfully